# Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies... Incompatible version constraints on code_transformers

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

Below is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: MyApp
description: A sample command-line application
dependencies:
  csv_sheet: any
  redstone: any
  shelf_static: any
  browser: any
  angular: ">=0.14.0 <0.15.0"
  polymer: ">=0.13.0"
  core_elements: ">=0.2.0+1"
  paper_elements: ">=0.1.1+2"
```

I am getting the follow error

```
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Incompatible version constraints on code_transformers:
- angular 0.14.0 depends on version >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0
- polymer 0.13.0 depends on version >=0.2.0 <0.3.0
```

So angular and polymer are using different version of code_transformers.

Is there a combination of angular and polymer version constraint that will make my pubspec.yaml work?

Comment: Wow, dependency sharing between dependencies.  This will not end well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
dependency_overrides:
  code_transformers: '>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
```

to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

This is at your own risk as Angular is not tested with this `code_transformers` version.
As alternative you can use an older version of Polymer or wait for the next Angular release.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.  So right now there angular and polymer cannot be used together simply because they have different version of same dependency.  Why can't they both not share the dependency?  Would you agree this would create tremendous amount of problem down the road?  Unless there is some justification for this design I am missing.

Comment: Well, they both depend on that package (as in they both need it to work), so they have to declare that dependency in their pubspecs.  Hopeully, once the packages (angular, polymer, and their dependencies) mature enough, this should stop being a problem.  Right now, given that they're pre-1.0.0, and so are some of their dependencies, it's understandable (even if annoying) that there will be dependency clashes like these.

Comment: Theoretically they would need to test each possible combination of dependencies within the declared version constraints and also all possible versions of transitive dependencies. With a handful of dependencies this can become a huge number of possible combinations. To avoid problems they make the version constraints rather limiting. Because Polymer and Angular don't have their release dates synchronized (hardly possible) such situations occur. As @Tonio said this will get better when there are not so many changes in all related packages and especially less probably breaking changes.